# Different processing of selectors in the namespace routing examples

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can anyone please clarify to me what the controller selectors really are? I like to implement my own controller convention which will be similar to the examples of namespace routing in the official documentiation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Both example contains a very similar code to apply a custom route template string:

**1. Example of the application model convetion:**

```
...
controller.Selectors[0].AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
{
  Template = controller.ControllerType.Namespace.Replace('.', '/') + "/[controller]/[action]/{id?}"
};
```

**2. Example of the controller model convention:**

```
...
foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
{
  selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
  {
      Template = template.ToString()
  };
}
```

The first example creates a `new AttributeRouteModel()` **only for the first** selector while the second one creates **for all**.

So I'm confused at this point. Can any controller have more than one selector? If yes what would be those selectors? Is there any official/unofficial explanation for this?